# How to use Benewake CE-30C Solid State 3D Lidar with ROS for getting point cloud?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, 3d-slam, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a benewake CE-30C Lidar. [Link](http://www.benewake.com/en/ce30.html)
I can see how to interface Rp-lidar or Velodyne Lidars, but I can't find much support for this. Can somebody guide me as to how to get the point cloud data that is readable by ROS.

[Operational Manual of Lidar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wGBsOmfWhVazFPeThENzNickU/view)

[CE30 Linux SDK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wGBsOmfWhVenpGaW51M1ZKWVk/view)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301565/how-to-use-benewake-ce-30c-solid-state-3d-lidar-with-ros-for-getting-point-cloud?/) by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-08-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless someone else already did the work for you, you'll probably have to write a ROS driver for this device.

Luckily the manual you linked has this to say about the SDK:

> SDK is mainly used to develop applications of this LiDAR on Linux system by using C/C++, [..]

so Linux support seems to be ok (or at least: the SDK is usable on Linux).

If the device is more like a Laser Scanner (ie: outputs something akin to scans), you could perhaps use the Velodyne drivers as inspiration.

If it's more like a "traditional" 3D depth camera (ie: outputs point clouds directly), then it might perhaps make more sense to look at the ROS drivers for various depth cameras.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on 2018-08-25**:
I have found a driver on Github [Zlite/benewake](https://github.com/zlite/benewake)
There are no tutorials, could you explain how to view this data in Rviz and use it for generating a map?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-25**:\

> There are no tutorials, could you explain how to view this data in Rviz and use it for generating a map?

I'm afraid I won't have time for that.

I can only suggest to ask the original author how to use his nodes, and to look up the tutorials on how to visualise things in RViz.